# 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Repeater' does not contain a property with the name 'SelectedValue'

Tags: vb.net, repeater, selectedvalue

I am not sure what I am supposed to write in the code behind for my vb.net project. I have a repeater that filters a gridview. When trying to declare the scalar variable @CompanyID, I get the error I mentioned in the title of this post. Can someone help me? I have tried to look for the answer on many forums, but I can't find the right answer.

```
dsLetters.SelectCommand = "SELECT DISTINCT LEFT(ProductName, 1) AS [Letter] 
                          FROM Product, CompanyLink, Company 
                          WHERE Product.ProductID = CompanyLink.ProductID 
                          AND CompanyLink.CompanyID = Company.CompanyID 
                          AND Company.CompanyID = @CompanyID"

    'declaring scalar variable @CompanyID
    dsLetters.SelectParameters.Clear()
    Dim cp As ControlParameter = New ControlParameter
    cp.ControlID = "rptLetters"
    cp.DefaultValue = "-1"
    cp.Name = "CompanyID"
    cp.PropertyName = "SelectedValue"
    cp.Type = TypeCode.Decimal
    dsLetters.SelectParameters.Add(cp)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is that repeaters don't have the concept of a selected value; all they do is show what you have selected. What you may need to do is mimic the repeater values in a hidden dropdownlist and add client-side code to choose the appropriate value in the dropdownlist, then bind your ControlParameter to this property.